# как добавить кавычки в innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

```
joke.innerHTML = rJoke.value;
```

как сделать ,чтобы на странице отображалось 
"rJoke.value" ?
А не просто rJoke.value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
joke.innerHTML = `"${rJoke.value}"`;
```

```js
var rJoke = {
  value: 'A cowboy walks into a bar.'
};
var joke = document.getElementById("joke");
joke.innerHTML = `"${rJoke.value}"`;
```

```html
<div id="joke"><div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно классически экранировать их добавив перед ними слеш.

```js
document.body.innerHTML = "\"экранированные кавычки\"";
```